# How to avoid exception stack in response body

Tags: spring-mvc

I am currently using Spring MVC 3.0.6. My expectation is whenever any exception is thrown at Spring level (i.e.- before reaching request to my controller), no exception stack will be returned as response body. When expected result is HTML then control goes to an error page containing custom error message. In this scenario outcome is matched with my expectation.

But I am facing problem while expected result is JSON. In this scenario I am getting exception stack as JSON format.

e.g.-

Requested URL - /MyApp/secure/employee/name.json?employee=815009&.........

Let say by URL tampering one put employee= 815003333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333339 (means huge payload).

Now I am getting response like –

{ "exception":{"value":"8150………..9",
"errorCode":"typeMismatch","requiredType":"long","propertyName":null,"propertyChangeEvent":null,"message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value \"8150…………9\" from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"8150…………………..9\"","rootCause":{"cause":null,"message":"For input string: \"8150………………………9\"","localizedMessage":"For input string: \"8150…………..9\"","stackTrace":[{…………………..}]}}

My expected response will be like –

{"value":["Some custom error message"],"success":false}

**Note : In my controller I expect employee as long (data type) in @RequestParam.**

My concern is, as exception stack contains details about library from which exception is propagated might make my application vulnerable from security perspective.

Is there any way to return custom message instead of exception stack?

Comment: Show us the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle the amount of detail regarding exception you want to send back to caller.

I belive `@ControllerAdvise`is useful here. you can just drop the stack trace and just return a user friendly message. (log before you drop stack trace)

More information on its usage can be found [here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Vishnu. I want to mention one point that I am currently using Spring MVC-3.0.6. @ControllerAdvise is introduced in Spring MVC 3.2. I will try using mentioned other solutions.

Comment: The other solutions helped..?

Comment: Vishnu, I have developed one custom Exception Resolver by implementing_ org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver_
 and my custom exception resolver only intercept JSON type (i.e.- URL contains .json) request. In this resolver I am preparing custom message.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: would you mind marking it as an answere if it has helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: Downvoted for incorrect answer - doesn't work for Spring version mentioned in question.